# Moving wp from a server to another, with different administrator

Tags: media-library, migration, export, customization

Hi a friend had a website made by a guy, now he asked me to make him a new website but he want me to add all the post and pictures he had on the old one.

The problem is that the guy that made him the wp website doesn't want to give him the administrator password, he said he'll give me all the file i need, but he can't give the admin pass.

now we are having an issue. he gave me the whole "uploads" folder, the db file, and the file exported from wp -> tools -> export

but if i try importing just the db, it asks me for the old admin password, so i can't use it.
i tried importing the wp export file, and uploading the "uploads" folder via FTP, and it load all the news but it won't load the images as featured image.

I told him to use DownML to export the media library, he did that, but when he gives me the link of the DownML exported file ( the one that is given after the exporting process ) i try to download it and it gives me a permission error. He says that he tried changing permissions but it doesn't work. 
Could be its a file too big ? ( about 2gb )

how can i fix this issue? i need to have all the news back, and with all their featured images...

Comment: If you could reset the Admin password for the old DB dump, would that help? Because if you have access to the DB tables with something like PHPMyAdmin it's really easy and I can tell you how in a proper answer.

Comment: how could i reset the pass? can i do that just opening the db and looking for the pass string?

Comment: Hi, did the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way around this is probably to reset the Admin password on the old Database. If you have PHPMyAdmin or a very similar DB admin interface, do the following:

1. Import the old database.
2. Open the user's table, usually called 'wp_users'.
3. Find the user you wish to change the password for, and replace the contents of the 'user_pass' field with a plain text password. i.e "mypassword".
4. IMPORTANT: WordPress expects the password to be hashed as MD5. So before saving the record, set the 'Function' dropdown to 'MD5'. See screenshot:

[image]

5. Save the record and try to login.

If you don't have PHPMyAdmin or similar and want to set the password manually in a SQL dump file, you can generate an MD5 hash of a plain text password in several ways:

1. If you're on Mac/Linux, do the following in terminal:
   openssl md5 <<< mypassword
2. You can use an [online generator](https://www.google.co.uk/?q=online%20md5%20hash%20generator)